# Docker first user with docker

Tags: docker, gerrit

I'm trying to create a docker image of a gerrit instance contening just an admininstator.
I have no problem to create gerrit instance but I can't create the admin user.

Have you an idea to create this first user ?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation states](https://review.openstack.org/Documentation/install-quick.html):

> The first user to sign-in and register an account will be automatically placed into the fully privileged Administrators group, permitting server management over the web and over SSH.
>   Subsequent users will be automatically registered as unprivileged users.

So depending on your [authentication method](https://review.openstack.org/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#auth), simply log in with a user.